# Why are Stackoverflow pages og:type "Website"

Tags: facebook-opengraph

Shouldn't `og:type` be `website` for the homepage and then `article` in this instance?

I'm building a discussion form and confused as to which type to use for the homepage and the discussion thread pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stackoverflow does not have a facebook app, so having the og:type of any page on stackoverflow does not matter.

The `og:type` is useful when you have a facebook app which creates open graph stories. So lets for example say that StackOverflow had a facebook app, and it created facebook stories when users interacted on the site. For example, "Hopstream asked a question on stack overflow" is a story created when you asked this question. For this to happen StackOverflow definitely needs `og:type` to be set as `question`, and an action on the type as `ask`. But since there is no facebook app, there is no point of having any `og:type` other than `website`.

The `og:type` of `website` is used when this **page** is shared as link, so `website` is good enough for StackOverflow.

Hope this helps.